# Set data extraction from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php

I downloaded a great script for the store locator of google, the parent programmer, has set that once, performed the search in the input field, the data are extracted from a json file, by calling a script.

according to this guide (https://www.bjornblog.com/web/jquery-store-locator-plugin/comment-page-6), ie that of the owner would be enough to create a connection file that I created:

```
<?php
$connessione = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "ca2solution");
if ($connessione->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $connessione->connect_errno . ") " . $connessione->connect_error;
}
```

and include this php code, to extract instead of from the .json file, directly from the database:

```
$results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM locations");
$locations = array();

foreach($results as $location){
    array_push($locations, $location);
}

//Output JSON
echo json_encode($locations);
```

the code is divided into two phases index where inside there is the form that as action has set submit.html

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Map Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/storelocator.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="bh-sl-container">
    <div id="page-header">
        <h1 class="bh-sl-title">Using Chipotle as an Example</h1>
        <p>I used locations around Minneapolis and the southwest suburbs. So, for example, Edina, Plymouth, Eden Prarie, etc. would be good for testing the functionality.
            You can use just the city as the address - ex: Edina, MN. METTICE </p>
    </div>

    <div class="bh-sl-form-container">
        <form id="bh-sl-user-location" method="get" action="submit.html">
            <div class="form-input">
                <label for="bh-sl-address">Enter Address or Zip Code:</label>
                <input type="text" id="bh-sl-address" name="bh-sl-address" />
            </div>

            <button id="bh-sl-submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

submit.html:

```
<?php
include '../connessione.php';
?

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Map Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/storelocator.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="bh-sl-container">
    <div id="page-header">
        <h1 class="bh-sl-title">Using Chipotle as an Example</h1>
        <p>I used locations around Minneapolis and the southwest suburbs. So, for example, Edina, Plymouth, Eden Prarie, etc. would be good for testing the functionality.
            You can use just the city as the address - ex: Edina, MN.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="bh-sl-form-container">
        <form id="bh-sl-user-location" method="post" action="#">
            <div class="form-input">
                <label for="bh-sl-address">Enter Address or Zip Code:</label>
                <input type="text" id="bh-sl-address" name="bh-sl-address" />
            </div>

            <button id="bh-sl-submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="bh-sl-map-container" class="bh-sl-map-container">
        <div id="bh-sl-map" class="bh-sl-map"></div>
        <div class="bh-sl-loc-list">
            <ul class="list">
                $results = $connessione->query("SELECT * FROM locations");
                $locations = array();

                foreach($results as $location){
                    array_push($locations, $location);
                }

                //Output JSON
                echo json_encode($locations);
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/libs/handlebars.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCPi_BiC2r0ZOw-4eyXTVcxTpCMv4FOils"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/plugins/storeLocator/jquery.storelocator.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#bh-sl-map-container').storeLocator({
            'querystringParams' : true,
            'fullMapStart': true,
            // I seguenti percorsi sono impostati perché questo esempio si trova in una sottodirectory
            'dataLocation': '../data/locations.json',
            'infowindowTemplatePath': '../assets/js/plugins/storeLocator/templates/infowindow-description.html',
            'listTemplatePath': '../assets/js/plugins/storeLocator/templates/location-list-description.html'
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

but unfortunately I do not get any results, where am I wrong?

Comment: The literal PHP in `<ul>` will not usually execute. And using another `'dataLocation':` for the `.storeLocator()` is not likely to pick it up anyway. Do more debugging using the console, and reread the article. It mentions a separate php script to return results.

Comment: oh so what should I do?